# Лафоре Р. - Объектно-ориентированное программирование в С++

Tags: компилятор, c++

Здравствуйте!

Купил я эту книжечку, Лафоре Р. - Объектно-ориентированное программирование в С++. В основном изучение и написание консольных программ. Но в книге не написано, какой компилятор мне использовать. Я начинающий программист, и хочу писать под Windows и под мобильные устройства. Работаю в области программирования микроконтроллеров в С и разработки электронных устройств. И вот вопрос, какой компилятор лучше бы подошёл под этот учебник, с учётом моих желаний и моей специальности?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Под Windows промышленным стандартом де-факто является Microsoft Visual C/C++. Его и используйте. Вам будет достаточно скачать Visual C++ Express с сайта Microsoft. Когда нужны дополнительные процессорные оптимизации, работают с Intel C Compiler, но в начале обучения это не нужно.

Answer (score 2):

Мне больше нравится GNU GCC. Под Windows есть MinGW. Очень многие рекомендуют учиться именно на этом компилятора, если знаешь его будешь и другие знать. Для embedded он тоже используется, по своему опыту небольшому могу сказать. А так же еще можно использовать кросс-компиляторы, как раз тоже собранные из исходников gcc.